# Apex 5.1: Create a Select List with Database Column Values

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a column in my database (CAMPAIGN_NAME) and I want my users to be able to select any of the current campaigns in the system so they can see some charts by Campaign. Since we add campaigns all the time, I cannot use a list of Static Values, I need to be able to retrieve the current values from the CAMPAIGN_NAME column for the user to select one or several. I tried using a Select List with a List Of Values from an SQL Query (SELECT CAMPAIGN_NAME FROM LEAD_MATRIX) but it doesn't do the trick. Do you happen to know how to workaround on this? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: "it didn't work" is not an error message or a useful description of what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Good database design would assume that there is also a unique id for each name.

With that said try the following for your dynamic lov:

```
SELECT CAMPAIGN_NAME as display_val
      ,CAMPAIGN_ID as read_val
FROM LEAD_MATRIX
Order by CAMPAIGN_NAME
```

If you don't have a unique id for each name I'd encourage you to get one.

You'll need to ensure that your reports are leveraging this Id as well.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad you were able to solve the issue. Please select the answer the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to make LOV using such query as below:

```
SELECT CAMPAIGN_NAME AS D ,CAMPAIGN_NAME AS R FROM LEAD_MATRIX
```

But it's not good practice. I recommend you to create primary key and store that key value in target tables (for example for report purposes).

Then your query should be like:

```
SELECT CAMPAIGN_NAME AS D ,CAMPAIGN_ID AS R FROM LEAD_MATRIX
```